# Counting how many times a string shows in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
 X1           X2      

 Fox          A/B/C/D
 Duck         A/B/E/F
 Bird         A/E/G
```

And I want to count how many times the values in X2 shows up (without manually entering the letters to count).

The result would be:

```
X1   X2 (counts)
A    3
B    2
C    1
D    1
E    2
F    1
G    1
```

I have no idea on how to begin with this :(

Comment: What does the first column `X1` have to do with anything?

Is another way to formulate the question: I have a vector `X2`, and I want to generate a data.frame such that the first column of the data frame consists of all unique letters that exist in `X2`, and the second column is the number of times that letter occurs across `X2`? 

Is there any meaning to how the unique elements of `X2` are broken up? I.e., does it matter that it's ('A/B/C/D', 'A/B/E/F', ...) and not ('A/A/B/B/C/D/F...')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the column at the `/`, get the frequency count with `table` and `stack` to a two column `data.frame` in `base R`

```
stack(table(unlist(strsplit(df1$X2, "/", fixed = TRUE))))[2:1]
```

-output

```
  ind values
1   A      3
2   B      2
3   C      1
4   D      1
5   E      2
6   F      1
7   G      1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c("Fox", "Duck", "Bird"), X2 = c("A/B/C/D", 
"A/B/E/F", "A/E/G")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```